# Viewport Android Fit to screen

Tags: android, viewport

I'm working on a website (it is not responsive) and I want to fit to screen when I access it from mobile.
On iPhone it is ok, it fits. But on android it has zoom to phone resolution or something.

This is my viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
```

Not like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set width to `device-width`,So change

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
```

to

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;' />
```

Comment: It is still with zoom in

Comment: @NistorCristian please clear your project and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the scaling. Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Also have a look at this:
[WebView in Android 4.4 and initial-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243602/webview-in-android-4-4-and-initial-scale)